# Changing Parameter values passed to method from web service dynamically

Tags: c#, webforms, asmx

I am trying to encode almost all input on an asmx webservice using attributes, I am unsure of how to achieve that, I was thinking of passing the method to the parameter of the attribute, but somehow that made little sense in my head afterwards. So, is it possible to use an attribute to change the parameter values of a method? Or is there a way to achieve something close to that?

My thinking was to use Reflection and a custom attribute to access the method parameters and auto encode any string related values as only primitive types are used in the service. But I am unsure as to how an attribute can access the method its applied to and change its parameter values. Code wise I cannot provide anything as I am unsure how to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's *very* hard to understand what you're trying to describe at the moment. A concrete example would make it much, much clearer.

Comment: Having only 1 method, you want to pass any parameter and the webservice has to execute exactly what you want based on your parameters? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Basically what i want is to encode the webservice arguments so as to eliminate possible attacks from users without having to encode every input from the user.